# Background vs foreground task and running tasks in parallel

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, scripting, background-process

Since I'm new to Linux, apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology.

I'm trying to run a number of tasks in parallel (using the background shell operator). However, I need to first run two tasks in parallel followed (only after completion) by the rest of the tasks that depend on the outcome of the first two.

For example, suppose tasks `A.1` and `A.2` can run in parallel (no dependency between them) and produce some files that will be used by tasks `B.1`, `B.2`, and `B.3`. All the `B` tasks are independent; however, they cannot start until `A.1` and `A.2` finish in order to see the files. With this in mind, I came up with the following shell scripts:

`script1` has the following lines:

```
./A.1 & 
./A.2 &
```

`script2` has the following lines:

```
./B.1 &
./B.2 &
./B.3 &
```

`script3` simply calls scripts 1 and 2 sequentially (i.e., without the `&` operator) as follows:

```
./script1
./script2
```

I'm not sure if `script3` is what I'm looking for. Am I doing it right? In other words, will `script2` wait until `script1` finishes and then starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't do what you want. 
But it's actually simpler than that.

First of all, at a simple level, your analysis is correct. 
If `script3` says

```
./script1
./script2
```

then, yes, `script3` will wait for `script1` to finish,
and then it will start `script2`. 
The problem is that `script1` will "finish" essentially immediately —
i.e., in the amount of time it takes to spawn the two `A` processes —
and so the `B` commands will be started
while the `A` commands are still running.  Not what you want.

The solution is

```
./A.1 &
./A.2 &
wait
./B.1 &
./B.2 &
./B.3 &
```

The `wait` command (as its name suggests)
waits for the existing asynchronous processes to terminate before it proceeds.

The `wait` command must be executed by the same shell
that spawned the `A` processes.  You could put all six commands
into a single script, or the first three in one and the last three in another,
or various other combinations.

Also, you might want to do a `wait` after the `B` commands, too.